# "Inference for polymorphic keyword functions not supported"

Tags: parametric-polymorphism, typed-racket

The following code produces the titular error:

```lisp
(: f (∀ (a) (-> [#:x a] (U Integer a))))
(define (f #:x [x #f]) (or x 0))

(f #:x 3)
```

OK, but `(f #:x (cast 3 Integer))` still produces the same error. Where is the type variable whose reified value racket is trying to infer, i.e. the type variable whose value I need to explictly specify?

Note: I tried casting `(cast (f #:x (cast 3 Integer)) Integer)`, but DrRacket highlights only the inner `(f ...)` form wrt the type error.

Comment: If you're familiar with Haskell, the typed-racket equivalent of Haskell's `::` is `ann`, not `cast`. Think of `ann` like `::`, and `cast` more like converting types through `Data.Dynamic` or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is by annotating `f` itself, not the input or the output.

Also, you shouldn't be using `cast` for this, use [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29) instead of `cast` for assigning types to expressions. Using [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29) looks like `(ann 3 Integer)`.

There are 2 ways to annotate `f`, either [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29) or [`inst`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt)._inst))) will work.

#### [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29)

With [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29), you can refine `f`'s type to a non-polymorphic version of its type. The original type is `(∀ (a) (-> [#:x a] (U Integer a)))`, so the non-polymorphic version with `Integer` is `(-> [#:x Integer] Integer)`. Annotating `f`:

```
(ann f (-> [#:x Integer] Integer))
```

In context, annotating `f` within the function call:

```
((ann f (-> [#:x Integer] Integer)) #:x 3)
```

#### [`inst`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt)._inst)))

The example with [`ann`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._ann%29%29) is long because it rewrites a specialized version of the type of `f`. For specializing polymorphic types, the shorter way is with [`inst`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#(form._((lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt)._inst))):

```
(inst f Integer)
```

This automatically specializes the type to `(-> [#:x Integer] Integer)` for you, by replacing the type-parameter `a` with `Integer`. In context, annotating `f` within the function call:

```
((inst f Integer) #:x 3)
```